# Android Amazon DynamoDB 400 Bad Request error

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement Amazon Dynamo DB in my android application. Table created with Attributes such as id(string), status(number). I'm getting AmazonClientException  as "Unable to unmarshall error response". anyone suggest me.

Here my code is..

```
   try {
           AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = DynamoDB.getInstance();

                 Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
                 item.put("googleid", new AttributeValue().withS("Test"));
                 item.put("status", new AttributeValue().withN("1234"));

                 PutItemRequest putItemRequest =  new PutItemRequest("android_news_push",  item);
                 PutItemResult putItemResult = ddb.putItem(putItemRequest);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Exception is :

```
 09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (Unable to parse error response: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>UnsignedContentSHA256NotAllowed</Code><Message>The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header must be a valid SHA256.</Message><RequestId>B5B29CD73F1304CE</RequestId><HostId>qqkdFlfHognQw3zs//OcdyN9GDXDd84MFyi01ep8iMfseGFkz3z+MS9etRssS76v0H+A0IyJH1M=</HostId></Error>'). Response Code: 400, Response Text: Bad Request
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.putItem(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.dci.magzter.SplashScreen$4.onPostExecute(SplashScreen.java:260)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.dci.magzter.SplashScreen$4.onPostExecute(SplashScreen.java:1)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.dci.magzter.utils.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:640)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.dci.magzter.utils.AsyncTask.access$0(AsyncTask.java:636)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.dci.magzter.utils.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661): Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to parse error response: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>UnsignedContentSHA256NotAllowed</Code><Message>The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header must be a valid SHA256.</Message><RequestId>B5B29CD73F1304CE</RequestId><HostId>qqkdFlfHognQw3zs//OcdyN9GDXDd84MFyi01ep8iMfseGFkz3z+MS9etRssS76v0H+A0IyJH1M=</HostId></Error>'
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     ... 18 more
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661): Caused by: com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     at com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
09-11 05:58:14.473: W/System.err(1661):     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with your AWS credentials. Check if your keys are correct and also check if the access controls allows that operation.

You can see a similar issue [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=554438)

Hope it helps...